# PHP GeoIP loop error

Tags: php, html, loops, geolocation, geoip

i'm using a php redirection script, it gives me a continues loop error for the default redirection this is the code

```
<?php
// ccr.php - country code redirect
require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
$country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;
switch($country_code) {
case 'US':
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/en');
exit;
case 'FR':
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/fr');
exit;
case 'BE':
    header('Location: http://www.domain.com/fr');
exit;


default: // exceptions
    header('Location: http://www.domain.com');
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to set a flag if you have already tried to locate the IP, otherwise it will start over and over again after each redirect when your script is loaded. Or check if you are on the correct URL already, otherwise redirect.

Comment: If your default condition redirects back to the page you are on you're  going to end up in a loop. You need to change that behavior to something else.

Comment: @Quasdunk and how to do it please ?? I know the concept, but Im not a coder

Comment: @JohnConde Yes but how to do it ?? i'm not a coder :/

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're stuck in a loop is that your script is probably executed on every page an on every page-load.

You are most likely working with sessions, so the most convenient way would be to just set a flag there that you have already checked this user:

```
<?php

//...

// Do this only if the flag is not set
if( ! isset($_SESSION['checkedGeoIp']) )
{
  // Set the flag here so you don't need to set it after each case.
  // Now this will be set for all requests during the session and 
  // the above if-statement will prevent from checking and redirecting again
  $_SESSION['checkedGeoIp'] = true;

  // Execute the GeoIP logic...
  require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
  $geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
  $geoplugin->locate();
  $country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;

  switch ($country_code)
  {
      // ...
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you man, the problem is that script not working so I switched to Javascript one, if you can help i'll appreciate it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897314/javascript-geoip-loop-error